# Wagering on the stock market bounce was always a long shot. Now it looks like a sucker’s bet

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms

> Wagering on the stock market bounce was always a long shot. Now it looks like a sucker’s bet.

https://www.bnnbloomberg.ca/warnings-of-a-stock-market-bubble-finally-prove-too-much-for-s-p-500-1.1888080

What is 'a long shot'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "long shot" is an English idiom for [something that is unlikely to succeed](https://www.theidioms.com/long-shot/), in this case betting on stock market growth ("bounce").

> a bet with very low chances of winning.
>
> a proposition or attempt with low chances of succeeding

[The origin](https://www.etymonline.com/word/long%20shot) of the idiom is likely from the difficulty of hitting a target from far away:

> in the figurative sense of "something unlikely," 1867, from long (adj.) + shot (n.). The notion is of a shot at a target from a great distance, thus difficult to make.

Comment: In my opinion, *long shot* is closer to "hazardous or risky bet" than to "crazy wager".

Comment: I agree: A *long shot* is risky but it might pay off, it's not totally crazy. In the context of this headline, I think the writer is emphasizing that this investment was always risky, but in light of recent developments it now looks like a complete lost cause, "a sucker’s bet"

Comment: Yes, crazy creeps in when you bet more than you can afford to lose on a long-shot.

Comment: In the UK, I don't know about elsewhere, we can use 'long shot' to talk about a request or query that has a small, but not zero, chance of success, e.g. this is a long shot, but does anyone here know how to play the didgeridoo?

Comment: Yes, a very slim chance  also in AmE.

Comment: @Graffito I don't think "long shot" comes with any connotation about the amount of risk, only on the likelihood of success. Buying a single lottery ticket is a long shot, but carries very little risk.

Comment: Minor quibble not relevant to the asked question - in the context of the stock market, I read a "bounce" as a gain that follows after a loss or a downward trend, rather than continued growth. The analogy with a bouncing ball seems clear.

Comment: I agree, bounce is the "up" following a downward movement. In the context of this article, I guess the question is "how high will the ball bounce?", should we bet on more growth or not? I'll edit to remove "continued" if that's clearer.